# Angular2+ render a component without any wrapping tag at all

Tags: angular, dom, angular2-template, angular2-directives, angular2-ngcontent

My child-component looks like:

```
...
@Component({
    selector: '[child-component]'
    templateUrl: './child.template.html'
})
...
```

and my parent template like:

```
<span child-component [someInput]="123"></span>
```

now I want to render the content of my child component without the `<span>` container around it. I want no container at all in my parent component's template, just the content of our child-component's template.

I tried some other tags already.

- `<ng-content>` (nothing rendered at all)
- `<ng-template>` (Components on an embedded template:)
- `<ng-container>` (Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node')

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would say that it's not possible :(

Comment: Child components selector should be `child-component`, remove brackets and simple render `<child-component></child-component>`

Comment: @YashwardhanPauranik that will also lead to a container in the DOM.

Comment: Yeah.. without it it's not possible

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Finally found a working soltion!

My **child-component** looks like:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'child-component'
    templateUrl: './child.template.html'
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @ViewChild('childComponentTemplate') childComponentTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
}
```

My **child template** looks like:

```
<ng-template #childComponentTemplate>
  ... some content ...
</ng-template>
```

and my **parent template** like:

```
<child-component #wrapper [someInput]="123"></child-component>
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet='wrapper.childComponentTemplate'></ng-container>
```

This way there is no wrapper at all.

Comment: Wow... in 2022 this was my only solution. I am trying to convert a react app to angular. unfortunately I love using react fragments and there is no equivalent in angular so this Hack is a life saver. Thanks a million

Comment: I'm not really following this. Ok, maybe it won't result in any wrappers, but you will still have a mess in the dom.

Once rendered, won't this result in:

<child-component></child-component>
... some content ...

Which would still mess up things if used inside e.g. <tr>, <mat-select>, <mat-form-field>... and all other components that expect specific child components

Comment: This works a treat and while obviously not how we'd prefer to do it, get's the job done with only a couple extra lines. One thing to note is that by changing the child template property to `@ViewChild('childComponentTemplate', { static: true })` you can avoid the annoying expressionChangedAfterItHasBeenChecked issue since it won't be undefined when it loads.

Answer (score 8):

Your use-case can be solved by using CSS only, just set `child-component` as `display: contents`,

```css
child-component {
    display: contents;
}
```

As stated on `display: contents` [documentation](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents), this causes to appear as if the component were direct children of the element's parent.

Comment: It is a cool trick, but it is not what op want. He want to remove the element from the DOM, not just visually.

Comment: This answer appeals that maybe he doesn't need to remove the DOM :) the element using `display:contents` ignores itself, this is mainly useful when a wrapper element should be ignored when using CSS grid or similar layout techniques.

Answer (score 2):

This method can avoid ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError error.

**child-component**:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'child-component'
    templateUrl: './child.template.html'
})

export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
@ViewChild('childTemplate', {static: true}) childTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;

constructor(
      private view: ViewContainerRef
) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.view.createEmbeddedView(this.currentUserTemplate);
}

}
```

**parent-component**:

```
<child-component></child-component>
```

Comment: +1, just some details: `this.currentUserTemplate` should be `this.childTemplate` (Also reader has to refer to the other answers for what the child-components html should look like.)