# Create an angular component without wrapper tag

Tags: angular

I want to generate a component without its wrapper tag. I read all similar SO questions (e.g. [SO1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38716105/angular2-render-a-component-without-its-wrapping-tag), [SO2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52169086/angular2-render-a-component-without-any-wrapping-tag-at-all), [SO3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38287224/angular-2-component-without-selector-tag-in-dom)), without finding a proper solution.

My existing, simplified component (**toggle-button.component.ts**):

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "toggle-button, [toggleButton]",
    template: `<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">{{ label }}</button>`
})

export class ToggleButtonComponent {

    @Input()
    public label: string;
}
```

Second component, which I want to create (**select-button.component.ts**):

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "select-button",
    template: `
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
             <ng-container toggleButton [label]="item.label"></ng-container>
        </ng-container>
    </div>
    `
})

export class SelectButtonComponent {

    @Input()
    public items: {label: string; value: any;};
}
```

My **app.component.html**

```
<select-button [items]="items"></select-button>
```

The result is an error:

> Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': This node type does not support this method.

What I want to achieve is a HTML structure like this:

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">12 H</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">24 H</button>
</div>
```

Instead of:

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <toggle-button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">12 H</button>
    </toggle-button>
    <toggle-button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">24 H</button>
    </toggle-button>
</div>
```

Stackblitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e5lns8)

Comment: Can you create stackbliz example for this?

Comment: I've added one.

Comment: in stackblitz you are using component and in your question you are using attribute selector.

Comment: I use both attribute and css selector. But I've updated my stackblitz.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6whr8i?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-button.component.ts

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use that. I need to be able to use the toggle-button component simply by defining like `<toggle-button></toggle-button>`. Also it has some more complex logic, which I can't share here and it can't be achieved this way.

Answer (score -1):

The simpliest way is to avoid toggle-button.component.ts and insert  tag directly in the select-button.component html for example:

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">{{item.label}}</button>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but my toggle-button is more complex than in this example and I want to encapsulate that complexity outside of select-button. Also the toggle-button is a standalone component, which I use in other part of my app.